# What does the operator $\mathop{\large\mathrm K}_{i=1}^\infty$ stand for?

Tags: notation

There are many different operators, for example sums

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty$$

or products

$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty$$

But what does this operator stand for? What does it mean?

$$\mathop{\LARGE\mathrm K}_{i=1}^\infty$$

I am sorry for this might being a dumb question, but I tried googling things like "big K operator math" and didn't found anything.

Comment: one of the many notations for [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations_for_continued_fractions), this one is used by Gauss.